# Problem with program that searches a Hash Table using Linked Lists

Tags: c++, search, data-structures, hash, linked-list

I'm having a problem getting a function to work that searches a hash table for a given key value. See code below.

```
      //hashtable constructor
      Hashing(int tableSize) {
        TABLE_SIZE = tableSize;
        hashTable = new LinkedList[TABLE_SIZE];
      }

      //search algorithm
      bool search(int key) { 
        int hashVal = getHashValue(key); //returns (37 * val + 61) % TABLE_SIZE
        LinkedList hashList = hashTable[hashVal];
        for(int i=0; i<hashList.getSize(); i++){
            if(hashList->value == key)
                return true;
            else
                hashList = hashList->next;
        }
        return false;
    }
```

The problem occurs in the if statement and the code following the else, where I get the following error:

> error: base operand of ‘->’ has non-pointer type ‘LinkedList’

Now I know I can't replace the '->' with '.' like I would for any other non-pointer because the code doesn't recognize what that means for the class object.
What I'm trying to do is return true if the current value of the LinkedList (hashList) is equal to key, the value being searched for. Otherwise move on to the next value of the LinkedList and let the for-loop start over. How should I rewrite this code to get it working?

Thanks for any help!

Comment: Without telling us the definition of hashTable, we can only guess that it's content type is not LinkedList? That's what the error means.

Comment: @GemTaylor sorry, my bad. I have now included hashTable constructor in the code sample above. The hashList LinkedList I create is supposed to access the element of the hash table with the matching hash value of the provided key

Comment: Ah so now I grasp that you are trying to implement your own hashtable, One problem you have is that the line `LinkedList hashList = hashTable[hashVal];` probably makes a copy of the list in the base table entry - probably you want to take a reference. The second is that now I don't know what your LinkedList structure is? I assume that is to represent overflows in the hash table?

Comment: You have some weird `hashList` there. You can step through the list using `hashList = hashList->next`, yet at every node, you can get the whole size with `hashList.getSize()`?

Comment: @GemTaylor Solved it. The definition of LinkedLists was contained in a separate LinkedList.h file, which itself had a search function utilizing separate ListNodes. I was trying to perform a search from scratch within this function when I simply could've utilized the search function in LinkedList.h that I forgot was there.